How to disable performance measure events in Monaco editor
I'm using Monaco Editor in my web project, and when I input something in the editor, I found it will produce many measure events.
You can go to Monaco Editor website and reproduce it as displayed in following screenshot.
screenshot
I tried to set window.performance to noop (no operation) but it breaks other flows in my application that depend on the performance API.
I also checked the Monaco editor options and can't seem to find a solution.
Is there any way to disable these measure events produced by the Monaco Editor without affecting other parts of my application that rely on the performance API?
